# LTC3813 Boost Converter design help

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, inductor, boost

I'm working on a boost converter design for a lawn tractor conversion to electric. I use a 90v PMDC 2.5 HP motor (21 Amps nominal) from an old threadmill for load and 4 12v 100Ah AGM batteries in series for supply.I have some basic knowledge about electronics but this is above me and I need some help to learn trough it.

So I started from an LTC3813 reference design and adapted it to my need by changing top and bottom mosfet, main inductor and of course, voltage feedback resistance divider. See schematic below, you can easily reproduce it in LTSpice starting from reference design.
[image]

So my questions are the following:

1. Do you think LTC3813 controller is suitable for this application or is 90VDC too close to the max limit?
2. I'm pretty sure the MOSFET model I chose is not suitable after all: RDSon, total gate charge and thermal performances are great but, again, am I too close to the voltage limit considering back-EMF from a 21 amps brushed motor? would you happen to know interesting model candidates?
3. Is it normal to have quite large voltage dips (5-15 volts for 5-10ns) on Vout in LTSpice sim? I tried adding "real" parts instead of the basic C3 cap+ESR and the added equivalent inductance made it a lot worse. Should I worry about that?

Thanks
-Simon-Pierre

Comment: Hmm, 48 V to 90 V at Iload = 21 A "I have some basic knowledge about electronics". I hope you realize that a 21 A boost converter is a challenge even for the experienced EEs (unless designing those is/was your daily job of course). For example: in LTSPice any connection is ideal: 0 Ohms. In the real world it is easy to have several tens of milli ohms here and there, those resistances need to be kept in check. Do you have experience how to do that? Even if you would get this to work in LTSPice, there's no guarantee it will work in the real world.

Comment: Look at some designs of high power electronics and see how it is done. For example on Youtube:  For example: https://www.youtube.com/c/KaizerPowerElectronicsDk60 and https://www.youtube.com/c/EevblogDave High power devices often use not just one MOSFET but a couple in parallel.

Comment: I do realize it's a challenge but maybe not to its full extent. I intended indeed to put parallel devices so to be able to fetch accessible parts. Do you suggest I should review the whole design and go with something like an AC generator and transformer?

Comment: Thanks for the references by the way.

Comment: *Do you suggest I should review the whole design...* I'm only suggesting that you should gain more experience and that this is not a good project for your current skill level. You risk components melting and catching fire. Does the motor really need 90 V? What happens if you just give it the 48 V? Then a beefy switch and thick cabling might be all you need.

Comment: Yes I did just that and motor power is insufficient and irregular. I consider making an H bridge inverter with a power transformer